# Cannot Open Text File To Read Into Django Html

Tags: django, django-views

I have followed many of the answers provided here but I still cannot open the file.

I have an text file that I would like to render on my `home.html`.  I rewrote my **views.py** as suggested:

```
def homepage_view(request):
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'my_text.txt')
    data_file = open(file_path, 'r')
    data = data_file.read()
    context = {'intro' : data}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

Here is my **home.html**. The html includes: `from . import forms, from . import views`:

```
<div class="intro">
    {% block intro %}
        {{block.super }}
        {{intro}}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

My **app/urls.py** is:

```
from page import views

app_name = 'page'

urlpatterns = [

    path('home/', views.homepage_view, name='homepage_view'),
    path('upload/', views.csvUpload, name='csv_upload'),
    path('zip/', views.zipUser_view, name = 'zipUser_view'),
    path('results/', views.results_view, name='results_view'),
    path('ky_outline/', views.display_ky_image, name = 'ky_image'),

]
```

My structure is:

```
myproject/
    __pycache__
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
        my/app ('page')
            __pycache__
            migrations
            static
                page
                    css
                        style.css
                     images
                     media
                         my_text.txt
```

static and media settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

]

STATIC_ROOT = [],

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

What am I missing or have I looked at this too long?

Comment: Based on your configurations for handling static files, why your `static` directory is _under_ your app directory? Shouldn't it be beside the `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views, try to put the path manually instead of use os, if it's work then is problem of how you give the path to open()